# Where and how can I find and download Android 1.5 source code?

Tags: android, android-source

Where and how can I find and download **Android 1.5** source code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get a specific branch of the android source, you use the repo just like you would to get the latest version. After you follow the instructions on the info for setting up the machine in the links that were supplied by the other answers, you would run

```
repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b cupcake
```

That will pull the 1.5 version of the source code.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was really what i needed! 

But there has appeared another problem: the download freezes at
"Receiving objects: 6% (4414/71566), 5.77 MiB | 131 KiB/s". And every time it shows different percent. I wonder why...

Comment: I had that issue a couple times, just tried again, and eventually it worked just fine. It is probably something to do with losing the connection to the host.

Answer (score 1):

http://source.android.com - The homepage for the Android source
https://android.googlesource.com - The homepage for the actual Android source code.

http://source.android.com/source/download.html - Instructions for downloading the source code.

Answer (score 1):

I'd imagine you would get it from the android git repository? 
*Web interface:* https://android.googlesource.com/
*SDK:* http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Details on how to access it: 
 https://source.android.com/source/downloading

**Note, the repository contains the current version so the above is likely uninteresting to you.**

I found this though:

*Andriod 1.5 (cupcake):* http://androidforums.com/android-developers/1045-source-code-android-jar.html

*Via:* http://java.dzone.com/articles/android-zip-download-cupcake