# Where can I get Android 1.5 (cupcake) source code?

Tags: android, android-1.5-cupcake

I'm looking for the Android cupcake source code.

The *current* official source distribution on `android.googlesource.com` only has tags going back as far as donut. And all the links I've found that mention cupcake (such as [Where and how can I find and download Android 1.5 source code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164864/where-and-how-can-i-find-and-download-android-1-5-source-code)) all predate the Great Kernel.org Disaster, and are no longer valid.

It has to be available from somewhere...

Comment: I was thinking the sources JAR on Maven Central has the actual code, but checked that download, and it only contains the stubbed classes that you get with the SDK anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Download from here. http://repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com/google/android/android/1.5_r4/

Comment: Ah that's the one--I was looking at http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=com/google/android/android/1.5_r4/android-1.5_r4-sources.jar but it's the stubbed classes only.

Comment: I'm afraid that's just the Java sources, and I actually need a complete AOSP checkout --- but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I found this article : http://java.dzone.com/articles/android-zip-download-cupcake

You can download Android 1.5 here : http://rgruet.free.fr/public/android-1.5-cupcake-src.zip

Comment: I'm afraid that's just the Java sources, and I actually need a complete AOSP checkout --- but thanks anyway.